cloglog.sample.size function (Binomial distribution)
I was wondering if cloglog.sample.size  function from binom package in R can be used to calculate the sample size for the following model (Binomial dis with cloglog) which can be used for discrete time COX PH:
Gompertz_Model_Baseline <- glm(formula = event ~ exit,
                               family = binomial(link = "cloglog"),
                               data = Scania_PersonPeriod_Train)

